# How can I add labels in a plot where I've used the function `plot` and `points`?

Tags: r, plot, statistics, label, bayesian

How can I add labels in a plot where I've used the function `plot` and `points`?

I have the following code

```
    x<-seq(0,1,.01)
    alpha=2
    beta=3
    y<-dbeta(x,alpha,beta)
    plot(x,y,ylim=c(0,5.9))
    n=10
    y1<-dbeta(x,alpha+x,beta+n-x)
    points(x,y1)
```

And the display is

[image]

I would like to indicate with labels *this is prior* and *this is posterior* .Also indicating which parameters are being used.

I know how to add labels when you only use `plot(x,y,xlab="y axis")`

but not when combined with `points` also this form of labeled would not be that clear in the plot.

The labels not in the usual form as is x and y labels in the plot, but indicating inside the plot, this is *the prior* and *this the posterior*.

Could you please help?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can use the `text()` function...something like `text(x = .2, y = 5, label = "this is posterior")`. You can also use `paste0()` or related function to incorporate the parameter values, i.e. something like `paste0("This is the posterior. Alpha = ", alpha, " Beta = ", beta)`. You could also pass in parameter values for x and y to automatically place them in reasonable places.

Comment: And check out [this post](https://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2018/03/15/2246/) to incorporate Greek symbols...

Comment: @Chase `text()` works fine, thank you! .I think `paste0()` does nothing in the plot, I don't see it.

Comment: I think `paste0` needs to be used inside `text()`. Its just so you can have more automated labesl

Comment: yes @RAB - that's right...would need to be passed to the label parameter inside `text()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the comment of @Chase,

Using the function `text()`.

Example:

`text(x = .2, y = 5, label = "Posterior distribution")`.